# aspx change focus from different TextBoxes on the fly

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

I am trying to change the focus from one textbox to another while the character count in 
on textbox reaches 13 I am using the code below with nothing happening whatsoever:

```
if (!this.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("qtyFocus"))
            {
                this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "qtyFocus",
                    @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>function qtyFocus(){
                        var trckNumberLength = document.getElementById('txtTrackingNumber').value.length;
                        if(trckNumberLength == 13){
                            document.getElementById('txtQuantity').focus();
                        }}</script>");
            }

            txtTrackingNumber.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:return qtyFocus();");
```

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the line in the script that's doing

```
var trckNumberLength = document.getElementById('txtTrackingNumber').value.length;
```

Needs to be changed for:

```
var trckNumberLength = document.getElementById('"+txtTrackingNumber.ClientID+"').value.length;
```

The reason being that txtTrackingNumber will very likely have a different Id when it's rendered on the page so you need to use the ClientID property of the control instead of the id you defined on the markup.

Comment: Leave the change I suggested and add attribute to onKeyUp instead of onchange.

Comment: Thanks, yep just read that the onchange actually happens when the enter is presses or the textbox loses focus thanks anyways :)